# backbone - how to get the model when listening to "add" event on the collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, collections, model

first question here at SO :)
I'm workin on a backbone project and the main example I rely on is TODOMVC by Addy Osmani, but there's something I cant figure out:

on the Todo app inside AppView

```
this.listenTo(app.Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
```

calls

```
addOne: function (todo) {
            var view = new app.TodoView({ model: todo });
            $('#todo-list').append(view.render().el);
        }
```

when I try to do the same I get the collection as the todo param inside addOne.

so, how can I get the actual model that was added?

Comment: Are you sure? The `"add"` event callback should get [`(model, collection, options)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) as arguments. Any chance of seeing a demo on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net?

Comment: To add to Mu's response -- check out http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog -- its unfortunately easy to miss, but important documentation when coding with backbone. Also note that when you fetch on a collection it wont use add/remove etc but reset (not what you are doing here but a common missunderstanding).

Comment: @MichaelWasser: Actually it does use add/remove instead of reset now, the change was made in 1.0.0 and there's a flag you can use if you prefer the old behavior.

Comment: @shem86 can you please provide a demo so that we can help you. Because the code you provided in question seems fine to me.

Comment: my bad..
on my app I inspected the param, saw the collection property and got confused. the problem was somewhere else (I tried appending the view to an uninitialized $ obj).
probably the effects of late hours :)

thanks for Event-catalog link though, I haven't seen it before.